# How to calculate angle between two intersecting lines in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

If there is two lines line1 and line2 . How to calculate angle between these 2 lines.

If line1 has points {(x1,y1),(x2,y2)} and line2 has points {(x3,y3),(x4,y4)}

I know how to calculate the slopes .Any idea to calculate angle in flex.

Let the slopes is known....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var angleRadians:Number=Math.abs(Math.atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1)-Math.atan2(y4-y3,x4-x3));
if (angleRadians>0.5*Math.PI) angleRadians=Math.PI-angleRadians;
```

In short, get two slopes, subtract one from another, absolutize the result (the angle is positive) and since there are 4 angles around the intersection, so if we'll receive a bigger one, make a smaller out of it.

Comment: hi vesper.. iam getting values 0.12,0.15,0.25.  So what will be the angle from this (eg 85 deg or 60 deg )

Comment: Multiply this result by 180 and divide by PI. I've written "radians" on purpose.

Comment: Thanks ..for quick reply and exact answer

Answer (score 1):

When slope is knwon then you can calculate angle like..

SLOPE M = y2-y1/x2-x1   ,   M = tanX ,  angle X = arc tan(M)

Answer (score 0):

**CODE:**

Degrees between two vectors:

```
public function degreesTwoVectors(v1A:Object, v1B:Object, v2A:Object, v2B:Object):Number 
{
    var angle = (Math.atan2(v1B.y-v1A.y, v1B.x-v1B.x) - Math.atan2(v2B.y-v2A.y, v2B.x-v2B.x)) * (180 / Math.PI);
    if (angle >  180) angle -= 360;
    if (angle < -180) angle += 360;
    return angle;
}
```

Radians between two vectors:

```
public function radiansTwoVectors(v1A:Object, v1B:Object, v2A:Object, v2B:Object):Number 
{
    var angle = Math.atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1) - Math.atan2(y4-y3, x4-x3);
    if (angle >  Math.PI) angle -= Math.PI*2;
    if (angle < -Math.PI) angle += Math.PI*2;
    return angle;
}
```

**Usage examples:**

```
degreesTwoVectors(circle1, circle2, circle3, circle4);
```

or

```
degreesTwoVectors(circle1, circle2, circle2, circle3);
```

or

```
degreesTwoVectors({x:0,y:0}, circle1, {x:100,y:100}, circle2);
```

**Descriptions:**

```
//v1A: Object A of vector 1;
//v1B: Object B of vector 1;

//v2A: Object A of vector 2;
//v2B: Object B of vector 2;
```